# Unable to fetch Not Shared records

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, query-expressions

I have a scenario, to find the records which are not shared with access team.

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("task")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("activityid", "subject", "customid"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression()
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression("customid", ConditionOperator.NotNull)
                }
            },
            LinkEntities =
            {
                new LinkEntity("task", "principalobjectaccess", "activityid", "objectid", JoinOperator.Inner)
                {
                    Columns = new ColumnSet(true),
                    EntityAlias = "POA",
                    LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression()
                    {
                        Conditions =
                        {
                            new ConditionExpression("principaltypecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "team")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Result contains records which are shared and not shared.

***principaltypecode*** value contains either SystemUser or Team, in my scenario I am expecting records which are not shared with any team.

**Update:**
XrmToolBox has one plugin which helped me to find not shared records.

[image]

[image]

This plugin has the answer to my question but I need a c# Code to do this. Does anybody knows the mechanism of this tool to find such records?

Comment: i would assume that the POA table only contains records that are shared.....

Comment: There will always be 1 entry for every record in POA table as when record is created it will be shared with the owner user. If we share the record with team, 1 more record will create in POA. Now I have to fetch the records which are shared with team and subtract from all the records in the database. That is the only way out I see here.

Comment: @Nachiket XrmToolBox plugin uses the Solution 1 that I've posted in my answer below. You can check it using fiddler or other similar web debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have direct way to retrieve Records which are not shared.
But what you could do is

1. Get principalobjectaccess where regarding Record is Account or contact or so on
2. In this way you will have all the Accounts/contacts which are shared.
3. Now Iterate through all Accounts/Contact and check the Id's you fetched from principalobjectaccess  does match or not
4. In this way you could get list or Account/Contact (Records) which are not shared

   [image]

Comment: That s right. I have to try this way. I have a large data set.

Comment: @Nachiket Do let me know if this helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the database and `PrincipleTypeCode` is an [ObjectTypeCode](https://spandcrm.com/2017/08/14/dynamics-365-entity-type-code-list/) stored as an `int`, rather than a `string`.

[image: principalTypeCode]

8 is the object type code for `SystemUser`
9 is the object type code for `Team`

`principaltypecode` should never equal "team", so your current query returns everything.

You might want to try:
`new ConditionExpression("principaltypecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 9)`

Comment: This does not work. You will still get tasks that were shared both with users and teams.

Comment: What values are in the PrincipalTypeCode? There should be no 9's. Worse comes to worst, you can filter them out after retrieval.

Comment: Team or User. The thing is if a record is shared with both a user and a team the POA table will have 2 entries, one for the user and one for the team. So when using notequal to 9 the query will still retrieve the task shared with both because it will have an entry in the POA table not related to the PrincipalTypeCode 9.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure that a query can do what you want. You may be looking at running the existing query and then further filtering in code. I do it all the time in console apps - retrieve data sets and process in RAM. LINQ is very handy for this type of thing.

Comment: Yes, I will correct the code. What if I find the tasks records which does not have entry in POA table? will that work in my case?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Do a Left Outer Join between Task and POA table, retrieving only the acitivityId column and the principaltypecode column:

```
        var query = new QueryExpression("task");

        var principalObjectAccess = query.AddLink("principalobjectaccess", "activityid", "objectid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);

        principalObjectAccess.Columns.AddColumns("principaltypecode");

        var entityCollection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Then do an in-memory filtering to remove all entries in the collection where principaltypecode equals team. Beware that if you find an Id that fulfills this condition you have to remove all entries with that Id, this is important to remove tasks that are shared both with an user and a team.

**Solution 2**

This query will give you all the tasks that **are shared** with a team:

```
        var teamPrincipalTypeCode = 9;

        var query = new QueryExpression("task");

        var principalObjectAccess = query.AddLink("principalobjectaccess", "activityid", "objectid");

        principalObjectAccess.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("principaltypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, teamPrincipalTypeCode);

        var entityCollection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

After running it you just have to query for all task guids and subtract the ones returned by the query above. You can easily do this by using the Except method from System.Linq namespace.

Comment: It makes sense. It is going to take a while to execute and might be not feasible for the large data set.

Comment: @Nachiket Unfortunately, FetchXml is not as rich as SQL. In SQL this could be done in a single nested query :)